# PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory

Tags: php, list, get, subdirectory

How can I get all sub-directories of a given directory without files, `.`(current directory) or `..`(parent directory)
and then use each directory in a function?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` option.

**Option 2:**

Another option is to use `array_filter` to filter the list of directories. However, note that the code below will skip valid directories with periods in their name like `.config`.

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r($dirs);
```

Comment: that gives subdirectories as well?

Comment: You have to do a resursion here

Comment: Sorry, where is the GLOB_ONLYDIR option here??

Comment: @developerbmw Note the word **or**. He presents two different methods of attaining the goal.

Comment: While a nice, simple approach, the accepted answer does not answer the question: getting sub-directories from the parent directory (aka siblings of current working directory).  To do so it'd need to change working directory to the parent directory.

Comment: This ignores directories starting with a dot, ie. ".config"

Comment: Where to define the **PATH** for the directory?! `glob(string $pattern, int $flags = 0):` -- Ah, answered below. That should be specified in the answer.

Answer (score 195):

Here is how you can retrieve only directories with GLOB:

```
$directories = glob($somePath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: This also include the main directory.

Comment: This does not include the main directory in my case (Windows)

Comment: This doesn't include the main directory for me on mac linux either. Maybe it has to do with the path used?

Comment: This includes also the path `$somePath` in the output

Answer (score 63):

The Spl [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class provides a simple interface for viewing the contents of filesystem directories.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename().'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Almost the same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523839/php-read-number-of-dirs-and-then-require-for-each-a-specified-file-name):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($yourStartingPath), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        echo strtoupper($file->getRealpath()), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Replace `strtoupper` with your desired function.

Comment: nice thanks! one more question: how can I separate only the sub-dir name from the whole path?

Comment: @Adrian Please have a look at the API documentation I gave in your other question. `getFilename()` will return only the directory name.

Comment: To get rid of the dots, I had to add `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` as a second argument to the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$path = '/var/www/html/project/somefolder';

$dirs = array();

// directory handle
$dir = dir($path);

while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
       if (is_dir($path . '/' .$entry)) {
            $dirs[] = $entry; 
       }
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($dirs); exit;
```

Answer (score 8):

In Array:

```
function expandDirectoriesMatrix($base_dir, $level = 0) {
    $directories = array();
    foreach(scandir($base_dir) as $file) {
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        $dir = $base_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        if(is_dir($dir)) {
            $directories[]= array(
                    'level' => $level
                    'name' => $file,
                    'path' => $dir,
                    'children' => expandDirectoriesMatrix($dir, $level +1)
            );
        }
    }
    return $directories;
}
```

//access:

```
$dir = '/var/www/';
$directories = expandDirectoriesMatrix($dir);

echo $directories[0]['level']                // 0
echo $directories[0]['name']                 // pathA
echo $directories[0]['path']                 // /var/www/pathA
echo $directories[0]['children'][0]['name']  // subPathA1
echo $directories[0]['children'][0]['level'] // 1
echo $directories[0]['children'][1]['name']  // subPathA2
echo $directories[0]['children'][1]['level'] // 1
```

Example to show all:

```
function showDirectories($list, $parent = array())
{
    foreach ($list as $directory){
        $parent_name = count($parent) ? " parent: ({$parent['name']}" : '';
        $prefix = str_repeat('-', $directory['level']);
        echo "$prefix {$directory['name']} $parent_name <br/>";  // <-----------
        if(count($directory['children'])){
            // list the children directories
            showDirectories($directory['children'], $directory);
        }
    }
}

showDirectories($directories);

// pathA
// - subPathA1 (parent: pathA)
// -- subsubPathA11 (parent: subPathA1)
// - subPathA2 
// pathB
// pathC
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this function (PHP 7 required)

```
function getDirectories(string $path) : array
{
    $directories = [];
    $items = scandir($path);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if($item == '..' || $item == '.')
            continue;
        if(is_dir($path.'/'.$item))
            $directories[] = $item;
    }
    return $directories;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the one liner code:

```
 $sub_directories = array_map('basename', glob($directory_path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    /*this will do what you asked for, it only returns the subdirectory names in a given
      path, and you can make hyperlinks and use them:
    */

    $yourStartingPath = "photos\\";
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( 
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($yourStartingPath),  
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach($iterator as $file) { 
        if($file->isDir()) { 
            $path = strtoupper($file->getRealpath()) ; 
            $path2 = PHP_EOL;
            $path3 = $path.$path2;

            $result = end(explode('/', $path3)); 

            echo "<br />". basename($result );
        } 
    } 

    /* best regards,
        Sanaan Barzinji
        Erbil
    */
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Non-recursively List Only Directories

The only question that [direct asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47998817/430062) has been erroneously closed, so I have to put it here.

It also gives the ability to filter directories.

```php
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Theodore R. Smith <https://www.phpexperts.pro/>
 * License: MIT
 *
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168906/430062
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param bool   $recursive Default: false
 * @param array  $filtered  Default: [., ..]
 * @return array
 */
function getDirs($path, $recursive = false, array $filtered = [])
{
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("$path does not exist.");
    }

    $filtered += ['.', '..'];

    $dirs = [];
    $d = dir($path);
    while (($entry = $d->read()) !== false) {
        if (is_dir("$path/$entry") && !in_array($entry, $filtered)) {
            $dirs[] = $entry;

            if ($recursive) {
                $newDirs = getDirs("$path/$entry");
                foreach ($newDirs as $newDir) {
                    $dirs[] = "$entry/$newDir";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $dirs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper way

```
/**
 * Get all of the directories within a given directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $directory
 * @return array
 */
function directories($directory)
{
    $glob = glob($directory . '/*');

    if($glob === false)
    {
        return array();
    }

    return array_filter($glob, function($dir) {
        return is_dir($dir);
    });
}
```

Inspired by Laravel

Comment: This seems overkill when there is a flag `GLOB_ONLYDIR`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

The following recursive function returns an array with the full list of sub directories

```
function getSubDirectories($dir)
{
    $subDir = array();
    $directories = array_filter(glob($dir), 'is_dir');
    $subDir = array_merge($subDir, $directories);
    foreach ($directories as $directory) $subDir = array_merge($subDir, getSubDirectories($directory.'/*'));
    return $subDir;
}
```

Source: https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-get-subdirectories-in-php/

Comment: The question did not ask for recursion. Just a list of directories in a given directory, which was provided to them in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the glob() function to do this.

Here is some documentation on it:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

Find all PHP files recursively. The logic should be simple enough to tweak and it aims to be fast(er) by avoiding function calls.

```
function get_all_php_files($directory) {
    $directory_stack = array($directory);
    $ignored_filename = array(
        '.git' => true,
        '.svn' => true,
        '.hg' => true,
        'index.php' => true,
    );
    $file_list = array();
    while ($directory_stack) {
        $current_directory = array_shift($directory_stack);
        $files = scandir($current_directory);
        foreach ($files as $filename) {
            //  Skip all files/directories with:
            //      - A starting '.'
            //      - A starting '_'
            //      - Ignore 'index.php' files
            $pathname = $current_directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
            if (isset($filename[0]) && (
                $filename[0] === '.' ||
                $filename[0] === '_' ||
                isset($ignored_filename[$filename])
            )) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (is_dir($pathname) === TRUE) {
                $directory_stack[] = $pathname;
            } else if (pathinfo($pathname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'php') {
                $file_list[] = $pathname;
            }
        }
    }
    return $file_list;
}
```

Comment: The question did not ask for a list of files, or any recursion. Just a list of directories in a given directory.

Comment: I'm well-aware. At the time, I believe this was the top-answer on Google or similar, so I added my solution for those looking for a recursive implementation that doesn't blow the stack.

I don't see any harm in providing something that can be cut down to solve the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a recursive directory listing solutions. Use below code I hope it should help you.

```
<?php
/**
 * Function for recursive directory file list search as an array.
 *
 * @param mixed $dir Main Directory Path.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $fileInfo     = scandir($dir);
    $allFileLists = [];

    foreach ($fileInfo as $folder) {
        if ($folder !== '.' && $folder !== '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder) === true) {
                $allFileLists[$folder . '/'] = listFolderFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder);
            } else {
                $allFileLists[$folder] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }

    return $allFileLists;
}//end listFolderFiles()


$dir = listFolderFiles('your searching directory path ex:-F:\xampp\htdocs\abc');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dir);
echo '</pre>'

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Find all subfolders under a specified directory.

```
<?php
function scanDirAndSubdir($dir, &$fullDir = array()){
    $currentDir = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($currentDir as $key => $filename) {
        $realpath = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
        if (!is_dir($realpath) && $filename != "." && $filename != "..") {
            scanDirAndSubdir($realpath, $fullDir);
        } else {
            $fullDir[] = $realpath;
        }
    }

    return $fullDir;
}

var_dump(scanDirAndSubdir('C:/web2.0/'));
```

### Sample :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'C:/web2.0/config/' (length=17)
  1 => string 'C:/web2.0/js/' (length=13)
  2 => string 'C:/web2.0/mydir/' (length=16)
  3 => string 'C:/web2.0/myfile/' (length=17)
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer, as it can't be run.

Comment: @miken32 It is a complete answer, retry

Comment: where is the $filename? not complete answer @SkyVoyager