# return sub-directory name using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)

Is it possible to do this, using PHP and/or Jquery/Javascript:

1) open one folder from,say, a List-menu, then

2) select the sub-folder inside it.

I do not need the contents, but just the sub-folder name only. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @simone Thanks a lot, I just checked it out. 
However, mine is a bit different in that it's a manual two staged process : 

1) open a main-directory. 

2) select the sub-directory's name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. No, not via javascript (at least not when you want to get folderlistings from a machine which is not same as the client). This can be achieved by PHP. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php. By using `is_dir()` you can check if a file in a dir is a dir.

Note, if you want to get all subfolders from a certain folder you should create a function to get the folders from a folder (as mentioned above). Then use this function recursively each time you find a folder within the folder you're searching. See for example [What is a RECURSIVE Function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /*  to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }
}
```

also

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
list all files and folders in side tmp
```