# check path to see if there is any directory php

Tags: php, recursion, directory

How to check if in directory "713" there is any directory (not files)? it has to be smart enough to ignore file existance

```
    ...
    ...

    $workRecordFullPath = "/var/www/websites/AM_dev/app/webroot/files/submissions/57601/4189/713/";

    // check if folder "713" exists     
    if (file_exists($workRecordFullPath)) {
    // check if into 713 there is any directory
        if (!is_dir($workRecordFullPath)) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
```

Comment: If you want to check if it is a directory and it exists, then use `if (is_dir(...)) { return true; }`

Comment: I don't have name to check directory. I just want to check if there is any directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory

Comment: Please use appropriate tags, this has nothing to do with CakePHP at all, I've corrected your tags.

Comment: it's a cake application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...
    ...

    $workRecordFullPath = "/var/www/websites/AM_dev/app/webroot/files/submissions/57601/4189/713/";
    // get all directories in "713"
    $submissionWorkRecordFullPath = glob($workRecordFullPath . '*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    // check if folder "713" exists     
    if (file_exists($workRecordFullPath)) {
    // check if into 713 there is any directory
        if (!empty($submissionWorkRecordFullPath)) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
```

The other solution will be counting slashes "/"

```
  $oldQc = 12; // The deep number of folders to wrok_record_id

  $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
              new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($workRecordFullPath),
              RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
  );

  foreach($objects as $name => $object){

        // Name of all flies and directories
        $countSlashes = substr_count($name,'/');

        if ($countSlashes>$oldQc) {
            return false;
        }
  }

  return true;
```