# Check if directory have sub-directories PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get a file in a directory. This operation must be very fast.The inital directory can have childrens like `path/child/sub_child/sub_sub_child/aFile`. But a file can also be present before

- Path

  - Child
  - A file

  I do not care about which file I am getting I just want a fast way to get it.

I am stuck with this

```
        $h = opendir($path); //Open the current directory
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($h))) 
        {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') 
            { 
                echo $entry; 
                break; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2524151

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)