# php - Get List Of First Children Directory Names

Tags: php, iteration, dir

How to get a list of first children directory names inside a directory?

**Here is an example tree:**

```
dir /
    dir_first a /
                  dir second aa
                  dir second ab
                  dir second ac                 
    dir_first b /
                  dir second ba
                  dir second bb
                  dir second bc 
    dir first c /
                  dir second ca
                  dir second cb
                  dir second cc
```

I found the way of iterating through the dir [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524275/2232458), but this is listing all the second level childrens too and also their full paths, while I want only the directory's name like `dir_first a` etc.:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir_path), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->isDir()) {
        echo $file->getRealpath();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question right and you need same thing that is output right now but without the full path - use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). `echo basename($file->getRealpath());`

Comment: isn't it will output the last or in this case the second level directories?

Comment: so you only need dir_first a, dir_first b, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory Then this is what you need

Comment: You only need to use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**glob** allows you to enter a path and then use a flag to return only directories.

```
$files = glob('mydir/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
var_dump($files);
```

Comment: o, yes! that is! is there a way to select the output order? I mean ascending or descending? I am still prefer to use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, but I will accept this if this is the only way.

Comment: The GLOB_NOSORT will return the files in the order listed in the directory.  If that doesn't work the way you want it to, you could use PHP's sort functions.