# How to use index.php to show content for sub directories

Tags: php

How do i use index.php in main folder to show content for different sub directories in that folder?

Ex :

```
/members/
/members/index.php
/members/change-password/
/members/change-email-address/
```

Is it possible? I want to keep the urls clean instead of using `index.php?change-password`

EDIT : The possible duplicate only shows how to get sub directories, I also need a way to use the index.php in main folder when someone visits the sub folders.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So what about you hack your site own??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)

Comment: I think you are looking for "URL rewriting"

Comment: Your can use .htaccess file to rewrite your url

Comment: do you mean +Indexes in the .htaccess?

Comment: I don't know whats so hard to understand in that question, @TimoF. correctly pointed to URL rewriting

Comment: @SrikanthKoneru Cleary the question is difficult to understand if only one user could figure out what you were looking for...

Comment: What you are probably looking for is [using .htaccess rewriting for SEO-friendly URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use htaccess for this eg

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/members/change-password/$ ./index.php?change-password [NC]
```

You can find more, if you search on internet.

Comment: small change was needed `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^change-password/$ index.php?change-password [NC] ` the `/` should be removed it seems.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory):

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r( $dirs);
```

Recursively:

```
function getAllSubDirectories( $directory, $directory_seperator ){
   $dirs = array_map( function($item)use($directory_seperator){ return $item . $directory_seperator;}, array_filter( glob( $directory . '*' ), 'is_dir') );

    foreach( $dirs AS $dir ) {
        $dirs = array_merge( $dirs, getAllSubDirectories( $dir, $directory_seperator ) );
    }

    return $dirs;
}
```

Comment: I am not looking to get a list of sub directories, @Timo F correctly pointed to url rewritting