# How to make created folders to automatically appear on my select option form?

Tags: php

So, I'm pretty much a newbie I would say but... I was looking for the info included in this topic question.

I can't give you any code examples because I have honestly no idea how to do it..
But I guess it will have something to do with loops.

Lets say.. I'm creating a folder somewhere on my ftp server, then I want something to checks specific directory that would scan names of folders and if there would appear a new one, php somehowly would add it to a form with selectable option with a name of the found folder.

I tried to find it but without any luck... I'm usually manage to find things and figure out.. but this very time I have even made an account here :<

Halp

Comment: You should use method for scanning directory of its content. You can achieve it by refering to this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory

Comment: @aslawin Thank you sir, now gotta figure out how to insert it into select option form

Comment: @aslawin update: Thanks man, I managed to generate it into select form as an option value and name : )

Comment: so if my comment satisfied you, please rate it ;)