# Getting direct path of directory which contain pages using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, filepath

- Root

  - First_Folder

    - First_Folder_Pages
    - First_Folder_JS(js script here for ajax)
    - First_Folder_DB(php script that is linked from ajax request)
  - Second_Folder

    - Second_Folder_Pages
    - Second_Folder_JS(js script here for ajax)
    - Second_Folder_DB(php script that is linked from ajax request)

How can I get the direct path on the folder with names containing `Pages` using jQuery or PHP

Expected Output is like: `../../First_Folder/First_Folder_Pages`  or `../../Second_Folder/Second_Folder_Pages`

Comment: It is not possible using jQuery as jQuery works on the browser.

Comment: Are you running the code in second_folder_pages or just reading the folders? I mean __FILE__ can give you some info about current page.

Comment: I want to get the directory on another folder with same level as `First_Folder_Pages` it is named `First_Folder_JS` i want to send it to AJAX request to be saved on database. I will update the illustration @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ i just updated `First Folder` same goes for second folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function w'd be enough for file list. Just make an ajax call to it, json_encode to output before send back to javascript

```
function scan($dir)
    {
        $output = array();
        $handle = opendir($dir);

        if ($handle != false) {
            while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
                    continue;

                $path = $dir . '/' . $file;

                if (is_dir($path))
                    $output += scan($path);
                else
                    $output[] = $path;
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

İf you want to add folders to array too, just change the if statement like;

```
if (is_dir($path))
    $output += scan($path);

$output[] = $path;
```

Also you can use RecursiveDirectoryIterator class too: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524275/6394185)

**UPDATE**

Just erase the "else" keyword if you want to add folders too in output.

If you call function like;

```
scan('/root/');
```

The output will give you results like;

```
'/root/First_Folder/First_Folder_file1',
'/root/Second_Folder/Second_Folder_file1',
'/root/Second_Folder/Second_Folder_file2'
```

But if u erase "else" keyword, you will get results like;

```
'/root/First_Folder',
'/root/First_Folder/First_Folder_file1',
'/root/Second_Folder',
'/root/Second_Folder/Second_Folder_file1',
'/root/Second_Folder/Second_Folder_file2'
```

Comment: hi, can you explain the part where you said change the if statement it is not clear for me