# How to list all directories in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can I list all **directories** in Yii2?

I know there is a [`FileHelper`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-filehelper.html) to list all files in a directory/subdirectory, but I could not list directory using that.

Of course I can use raw PHP to do this, but before that I want to check if Yii2 provides any sort of functionality for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Yii 2 does not provide such functionality, I also checked the latest version of [BaseFileHelper](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php) in the sources and didn't find it there neither. You can use plain PHP for it, here is one of solutions that can be found for example in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory):

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r($dirs);
```

For retrieving subdirectories, you can use recursion.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't included it! I am going to mark this _accepted_ as it answers my query.

Comment: @leninhasda Probably is not so common task as listing files. Also framework can't cover all such tasks. But remember, you can always post an issue in official Github repo and if you provide enough facts that is demanded and required and contributors agree with you - most likely it will be implemented and included in framework core.

Answer (score 4):

Since Yii 2.0.14 you can use [`findDirectories()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper#findDirectories()-detail) method:

```
$allFiles = FileHelper::findDirectories('/path/to', ['recursive' => false]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use [FileHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-filehelper.html).

```
$allFiles = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('/path/to');
```

after that, you can access all file with `$allFiles` variable.

Comment: thanks. but like i said in the question, i want to list **directories**, not files