# List all folders in directory (PHP)

Tags: php, directory, scandir

How can I make my code only display links to the folders and not the files in the directory?

```
$d = dir(".");
echo "<ul>";
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
$d->close();
```

Comment: $arr = scandir('dirname'); then loop $arr and test is_dir($item)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory

Comment: Looking for a much better generalized answer to this for arbitrary directories, returns an array, and can be recursive? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168906/430062

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$d = dir(".");

echo "<ul>";

while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
{
    if (is_dir($entry) && ($entry != '.') && ($entry != '..'))
        echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}

echo "</ul>";

$d->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to wrap your current code with a call to [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

```
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    if (is_dir($entry)) {
        echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the "dot" directories (`.` and `..`), use the following:

```
if (is_dir($entry) && !in_array($entry, ['.', '..'])) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! The only problem i got with this solution is that i get these dots beneath the folders, what's that about?

Comment: @Unknown The dots are another "directory", really it's the parent directory of whatever directory you are in.

Comment: I see! 

Is there a way to remove it from the code, or do i have to use css to remove it?

Comment: Btw, i LOVE this platform. So freaking fast answers, it's pure magic!

Comment: I've added a way to remove the dots

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the $entry is a directory:

```
$d = dir(".");
echo "<ul>";
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
if(is_dir($entry))
    echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
$d->close();
```

Comment: OBS! It was this code that worked out of the box with the dots!