# List all folders and subfolders in a directory using PHP

Tags: php, list, directory, subdirectory

What is the best solution to list all folders, subfolders on 1 sublevel in a directory using PHP. My folder structure is like this:

```
Main Dir
 Dir1
  SubDir1
   File1
   File2
  SubDir2
   File3
   File4
 Dir2
  SubDir3
   File5
   File6
  SubDir4
   File7
   File8
```

**I want to get this**

```
Main Dir
 Dir1
  SubDir1
  SubDir2
 Dir2
  SubDir3
  SubDir4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Get all subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524151/php-get-all-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory)

Comment: I'd go with [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) just use skipDots and check isFile to skip over non directories.